# Best book for preparation to read The Art of the Computer Programming

Tags: computer-science, education

I decided to read The Art of the Computer Programming by Donald Knuth. The problem is, that i'm in high school now, so i need a help with mathematics oriented book which help me to be prepared for it.
Thank you!

Comment: Just read the book and ask questions when you get stuck.

Comment: Also, Volume 1 begins with mathematical preliminaries.

Comment: Consider reading [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/).

Answer (score 7):

If to take one book, "Concrete Mathematics" By R. Graham, D. Knuth, O. Patashnik contains a lot of relevant material from discrete  mathematics and some of probability theory.

Comment: I'll look for it.

Answer (score 1):

The book is challenging, no doubt about it. The key is repetition. The book isn't a one time read. You have to keep going back to it after referencing several other books like "Concrete Mathematics" or the MIT OCW course on "Mathematics for Computer Science". It is a multi-faceted book and you might miss a few things the first time but you will start figuring stuff out by reading and talking to people as you go. So get started without a doubt.

Helpful Tip:

The book has a lot of proofs, and the foundation of any mathematical endeavour and in turn one that of computer science is to prove that a specific algorithm works. You can watch a few videos about proofs in the link I've pasted below: [[link]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0QSMy74A_g&list=PL_onPhFCkVQhcTMNJ_lZnUMDW4mazNzid&ab_channel=stanfordonlinestanfordonline)